# All indices of a number using recurrion

Tags: c++11, recursion

I am solving a problem in recursion to print all the indices of a number.
For example: arr[] = {8,8,10,8,8} and element = 8 then we should have output array as: {0,1,3,4}

I am not getting the output as expected.
Here is my code solution:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int allIndexes(int input[], int size, int x, int output[]) {
    if(size==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(input[0] == x){
        output[0] = 0;    
    }
    int ans = allIndexes(input+1,size-1,x,output);
    for(int i=1;i<ans;i++){
        output[i] = output[i]+1;
    }
    ans = ans+1;
    return ans;
}
int main(){
    int arr[] = {8,8,10,8,8},output[5]={0};
    int size = allIndexes(arr,5,8,output);
    cout<<size<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++){
        cout<<output[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why I am getting wrong?

Comment: The original `allIndexes` call writes a value to `output[0]`. Then it call `allIndexes` recursively, and that call also writes to `output[0]` first thing, overwriting the first value. No amount of shifting afterwards could recover the data already lost. The manipulations you perform on `output` array make no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care about the index of the found value, `output[0]=0` is of no interest, that should store the value of the current index. So there is a missing argument in the call.

And. You have to increment `output` as you did with `input` but only in the case you found the value.

Finally you forgot to print all the values `size-1` in the main should be `size`.

So:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int allIndexes(int input[], int size, int x, int idx, int output[]) {
    if(size==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(input[0] == x){
        output[0] = idx; // stores the index
        return 1 + allIndexes(input+1,size-1,x,idx+1,output+1);
    }
    return allIndexes(input+1,size-1,x,idx+1,output);
}
int main(){
    int arr[] = {8,8,10,8,8},output[5]={0};
    int size = allIndexes(arr,5,8,0,output);
    cout<<size<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        cout<<output[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```